# How to best create release notes from commit/workitems in ADO

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I have a pipeline that looks like the following

[image]

Where the CI build will go

- to Dev environment when changes happen in the dev branch.
- to Test environment for PR against master
- to UAT then PROD for releases.

each environment is separated into two stages, infrastructure and then application.

- The infrastructure stage is gated by manual intervention for approval by IT and it is only run if the repository is actually have git changes against a prefix /build that has all infrastructure setup.
- The application stage is gated by manual intervention for approval by Project Group

Currently, I am manually writing notes about the releases contains. I am not looking to change my hole setup, but looking for a solution where I can automate the note given to approval people from either commit messages or work items.

I don't think it makes sense to provide them with all messages since last time, so how do we possibly add special messages that only is added?

using work items (PBIs in ado), how do we get that information into the message?